# PHP Dynamically Create Apps

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I'm working on a CRM, based on DigitalOcean and User Registration.

I want to make it so that when user runs installer.php, a new CRM app will be created.

(Signup > Create app folder > Create app database)

I'm having trouble generating this App folders, as they must all have unique id's.

Let's say mycrm.com/crm-1/ has it's database crm-1, and so on ..

How can I programmatically create an app folder and database autoincrementing the id's for each registered user?

I thought of getting the last signed up user id and adding 1, but if 2 users sign up (and create app and database) at the same time, things would get messed up.

Is there a way to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: You should have a table outside of the generated crms that tracks this data. If your giving them a whole crm that would be useful to know who they are. Then it's a simple matter of using the autoincrement I'd from that table for it. You can set the primary key to be autoincrement, and use get last insert I'd, let the DB handle concurrency

Comment: What do you mean by "CRM based on User Registration"?

Comment: A page where the user registers or sign's up and then the CRM (app folder and databas) is generated upon registration.